# Open3D: embed Visualizer into GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-visualization, point-clouds, open3d

I'm using Open3D to visualize 3D point clouds I'm working on. For this purpose I'm using [open3d.visualization.Visualizer](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.visualization.Visualizer.html#open3d-visualization-visualizer). Works good. Now I'm wish to embed this window into a larger GUI, where I'd show two Visualizer windows and some text label below them. Basically, it would be a simple design with two Visualizer objects next to each other, and text displayed below them. The GUI module from the same lib is [here](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.visualization.gui.html). I can't seem to figure out from documentation if this is possible?
Is there maybe some other framework that would enable me to do this?

Comment: you could show minimal working code - and we will have code to start testing ideas.

Comment: There are examples here for Python - https://github.com/intel-isl/Open3D/tree/master/examples/python/gui  I am doing something similar but just one window.